# How to plot a grpah from values in a data frame with one of the columns as axis ticks in R?

Tags: r, plot

I formed a data frame whose entries are this:

```
     month       val
1  Apr. 2013  0.1820011
2  Aug. 2013 -0.1278371
3  Dec. 2012 -0.4365417
4  Dec. 2013  0.7253285
5  Feb. 2013 -0.8435299
      .           .
      .           .
```

There are 15 rows in the frame.Now I want to plot the `val` values on the graph and the entries of `month` should be shown as the tick marks on x axis. I executed this command:

```
plot(mat$val,type="o",col="blue", xlab = "Month", ylab = "Values")
axis(1, at=1:15,labels=mat$month, col.axis="blue", las=0)
```

but on the graph every alternate x-axis tick is shown as integer. So, first tick is shown as `Apr. 2013` but then next tick is `2`(instead of Aug. 2013), then third tick is `Dec. 2012` but then next tick is `4` (instead of Dec. 2013). Thus every alternate x-axis tick is shown as integer. How to resolve this?

Also how can I make the `at` parameter in `axis()` more generic? I mean right now I know I have 15 rows in my data frame so I put `1:15` in there but if there are more than this row next time then it will be wrong. So, how can I make to read from data frame and fill the `at` based on number of rows that are there in frame?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off plotting of the integer x-axis with `xaxt = "n"`.

```
plot(mat$val,type="o", col="blue", xlab = "Month", ylab = "Values", xaxt = "n")
```

And you can make a sequence the same length as the number of rows in your dataframe with `nrow(mat)`.

```
axis(1, at=1:nrow(mat), labels=mat$month, col.axis="blue", las=0)
```

Comment: that turns off integer plotting but alternate ticks from the `mat$month` are still skipped.in place of where at first integers were shown on alternate ticks, it shows nothing. it should show month names from `mat$month` which are skipped

Comment: @JasonDonnald - make your plot window a bit wider. R is suppressing the labels because it can't fit them in.